# Install of activerecord-jdbc-adapter from Github (51.1) fails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to install the latest jdbc adapter, as I want to use it with Rails 5.2.1. But during the installation this error occurs. As I am not into Java at all I have no Idea what to do. Any recommendations what to do?

I would really appreciate your help!

My java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Stack of the error:

```
Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter 51.1 (java) (was 50.0) from git://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git (at master@c5e1abd)
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51
/home/markus/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/jruby -rubygems
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake
RUBYARCHDIR=/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.3.0/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51
RUBYLIBDIR=/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.3.0/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51
rake aborted!
Caught NameError; examine $ANT_HOME
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51/rakelib/compile.rake:1:in
`(root)'
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51/rakelib/compile.rake:3:in
`(root)'
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
`<main>'

Caused by:
NameError: missing class name (`org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper')
org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:259:in `method_missing'
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51/rakelib/compile.rake:1:in
`(root)'
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51/rakelib/compile.rake:3:in
`(root)'
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
`<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51
for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/markus/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.17.0/bundler/gems/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.3.0/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-c5e1abdaaf51/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter (51.1),
and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter was resolved to 51.1, which depends on
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

this is an **ant** dependency that `gem '...', github: ...` required to build the extension.

has been **changed recently** (09/2018) and is now no longer required if you update the git repo.

for *51-stable* branch since this commit: https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/commit/9dbcf040715bb3d51dbe122bf521ea8ef2288293